# List of gear by statistics

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

I've been having a search around for a site which lists the various sets of gear available in game and shows their stats.

What are all the gear sets and what are the overall stats for each set?

So far I can see that Military is focused on Ranged, Medieval is focused on Health and Phantom on Stealth.

I'd like to see a definitive list of gear with each stat and know which sets focus on which attributes.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with a screenshot when my pc decides do transfer the screenshot from the iphone.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no Official Website with that information.

But that information is available in the **Assassin's Creed Unity Companion App**!

With the App you can even check stats in real time, for example, changing the different gear and seeing how that change affects your stats.

**Just go the top left corner and there will be a Menu Button to open a Menu. In the Menu Items there is one for Gear and there you have all the information you can get.**

[image: Gear Set]
Sorry for it being in Portuguese but I couldn't find a way to change it. But it's basically your Gear Menu Item.

You can download the app in the App Store for iOS and [Google Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubisoft.assassin.unity.companion) for Android.